# Filter multidimensional array by key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've looked into using reduce, filter, and map in other examples I've seen on SO, but I'm not sure if they fit my use-case. Say I have the following multidimensional array:

```
const variableOpts = [
  { id: -1, value: 'Select Variable' },
  { id: 1,
    value: 'Patient',
    options: [
      { id: 2, value: 'First Name', variable: '{first_name}', variableValue: 'Billy' },
      { id: 3, value: 'Last Name', variable: '{last_name}', variableValue: 'Bob' },
      { id: 4, value: 'Office Location', variable: '{office_location}', variableValue: 'Mount Pleasant' },
    ],
  },
  { id: 5, value: 'Another option', variable: '{another_option}', variableValue: 'Test' },
];
```

What I'd like to do is grab any objects that contain the `variable` key, whether they are a top-level item, or within an item; like the `options` array holds. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### Update

Ideally I'd like to have an array with everything at one-level so I can loop over them, like this:

```
[
  { id: 2, value: 'First Name', variable: '{first_name}', variableValue: 'Billy' },
  { id: 3, value: 'Last Name', variable: '{last_name}', variableValue: 'Bob' },
  { id: 4, value: 'Office Location', variable: '{office_location}', variableValue: 'Mount Pleasant' },
  { id: 5, value: 'Another option', variable: '{another_option}', variableValue: 'Test' },
]
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Should it keep the second item, but not the first? Because of key-`options`? Or the key-`option` was just an example?

Comment: Hey @WashingtonGuedes ideally it'd return `[
  { id: 2, value: 'First Name', variable: '{first_name}', variableValue: 'Billy' },
  { id: 3, value: 'Last Name', variable: '{last_name}', variableValue: 'Bob' },
  { id: 4, value: 'Office Location', variable: '{office_location}', variableValue: 'Mount Pleasant' },
  { id: 5, value: 'Another option', variable: '{another_option}', variableValue: 'Test' },
]` A one-level array that I can loop over

Comment: Yea, what are you expecting as a result from this? If an option doesn't have `variable` is that removed from the options list? Or is it just keep the top level value because it has `variable` or any of the options has `variable`.

Comment:  just updated, thanks

Comment: not related to the answer, that data structure doesnt make sense, why will the meta data of patient also be indexed by the same id

Comment: The `id` is a unique identifier used in React --- this would be the exact structure as mentioned in https://github.com/springload/react-simpler-select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using recursion, you can loop over the array, check each value for the key `variable` and if found append it to an array of good values. Then check if there is an options key, if found, recurse to check each option. Something like this:

```js
const variableOpts = [{ id: -1, value: 'Select Variable' }, { id: 1, value: 'Patient', options: [{ id: 2, value: 'First Name', variable: '{first_name}', variableValue: 'Billy' }, { id: 3, value: 'Last Name', variable: '{last_name}', variableValue: 'Bob' }, { id: 4, value: 'Office Location', variable: '{office_location}', variableValue: 'Mount Pleasant' }, ], }, { id: 5, value: 'Another option', variable: '{another_option}', variableValue: 'Test' }, ];

function findVariable(arr){
  //output variable
  var out = [];

  //loop over array
  arr.forEach(function(a){
    //if has variable key, add it to output
    if(a.variable){
      out.push(a);
    }

    //if has options, recurse and concat any with variable to output
    if(Array.isArray(a.options)){
      out = out.concat(findVariable(a.options));
    }
  });

  //return the output
  return out;
}

console.log(findVariable(variableOpts));
```

Comment: Wow so many great answers! I'm going to accept this one as you provided a great explanation and had inline comments. Thank you very much!

Comment: Nice recursion!

Answer (score 2):

You can first filter the objects that either have the `options` or `variable` keys, then normalize the results in a `for` loop…

```js
const variableOpts = [{id: -1, value: 'Select Variable' }, {id: 1, value: 'Patient', options: [{id: 2, value: 'First Name', variable: '{first_name}', variableValue: 'Billy' }, {id: 3, value: 'Last Name', variable: '{last_name}', variableValue: 'Bob' }, {id: 4, value: 'Office Location', variable: '{office_location}', variableValue: 'Mount Pleasant' }]}, {id: 5, value: 'Another option', variable: '{another_option}', variableValue: 'Test' }];

const tempOpts = variableOpts.filter(function(obj){
  return (obj.options && Array.isArray(obj.options)) || obj.variable;
});

const finalOpts = [];

for(let i = 0; i < tempOpts.length; i++){
  let currentOpt = tempOpts[i];

  if(currentOpt.options)
  {
    for(let i = 0; i < currentOpt.options.length; i++){
      finalOpts.push(currentOpt.options[i]);
    }
  }else
  {
    finalOpts.push(currentOpt);
  }
}

console.log(finalOpts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a recursive check while populating your resulting array:

```js
const variableOpts=[{id:-1,value:'Select Variable'},{id:1,value:'Patient',options:[{id:2,value:'First Name',variable:'{first_name}',variableValue:'Billy'},{id:3,value:'Last Name',variable:'{last_name}',variableValue:'Bob'},{id:4,value:'Office Location',variable:'{office_location}',variableValue:'Mount Pleasant'}]},{id:5,value:'Another option',variable:'{another_option}',variableValue:'Test'}];

var findObjects = function() {
    var isArray = function(a) {
        return a.map == [].map;
    };
    var isObject = function(o) {
        return Object(o) === o;
    };
    var result = [];
    var stepThrough = function(obj) {
        if (isArray(obj))
            return obj.forEach(stepThrough);

        if (isObject(obj)) {
            for (var key in obj)
                if (isArray(obj[key])) {
                    stepThrough(obj[key]);
                    delete obj[key];
                }
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty('variable'))
                result.push(obj);
        }
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        stepThrough(arguments);
    }
    return result;
};

console.log( findObjects(variableOpts) );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I really like my answer, but it seems to work.

```js
const variableOpts = [{ id: -1, value: 'Select Variable' }, { id: 1, value: 'Patient', options: [{ id: 2, value: 'First Name', variable: '{first_name}', variableValue: 'Billy' }, { id: 3, value: 'Last Name', variable: '{last_name}', variableValue: 'Bob' }, { id: 4, value: 'Office Location', variable: '{office_location}', variableValue: 'Mount Pleasant' },], }, { id: 5, value: 'Another option', variable: '{another_option}', variableValue: 'Test' },];

let result = [];

let checkArrayEntry = obj => {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty('variable')) result.push(obj);
    Object.keys(obj).filter(prop => obj[prop] instanceof Array).forEach(entry => obj[entry].forEach(checkArrayEntry));
};

variableOpts.forEach(checkArrayEntry);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something short and strait forward.

```js
const variableOpts = [{ id: -1, value: 'Select Variable'},{id: 1,value: 'Patient',options: [{id: 2,value:'First Name', variable: '{first_name}',variableValue: 'Billy'},{id: 3,value: 'Last Name',variable: '{last_name}',ariableValue: 'Bob'},{ id: 4, value: 'Office Location',variable: '{office_location}',variableValue: 'Mount Pleasant'},],},{id: 5,value: 'Another option',variable: '{another_option}',variableValue: 'Test'},];

var val = variableOpts.filter(item => item.id != -1)
val = val.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b.options || b), [])
console.log(val);
```

Comment: I really like this one!

Comment: @Zach me too, Reduce is probably one of the most powerful higher order functions. However, it's mastery takes time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a functional solution using map you could first define a flatten function

```
function flatten(arr) {
  return [].concat.apply([], arr)
}

function filterArray(arr, f) {
  if(!(arr instanceof Array)) return [];
  return flatten(arr.map(elem =>
    (f(elem)?[elem]:[]).concat(filterArray(elem["options"], f))
  ));
}
```

Then you can write e.g.

```
console.log(filterArray(variableOpts, elem => elem["variable"]&&elem["variable"].indexOf("name")>=0));
```

To get all elements that have the string `name` somewhere in their `variable` property.